Forgot system password
I got an old desktop from my neighbor that I want to use for my kids. The neighbor says he doesn't remember the password. The system boots to the system log on screen and asks for the password. How do I get around this?

I recommend to reinstall system and create new user. There are hundreds tutorials on YouTube, Linux blogs, or official website how to install Ubuntu.

This question is similar to: How to find out root password for installing software. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

... see also Given a used laptop with Ubuntu installed, how do I get past the password demands?

I tried getting to the grub menu by holding down Shift+Esc before seeing the "Ubuntu" icon come up, but nothing happens and I get right back to the Log In screen all over again
